# Pagination concept in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular6, angular5, angular-router

I am using two pages, product list page and product detail page.

In product list , I have 100 products. 10 products per each page. I used next and previous button for moving from one page to another.
[image]

pagination is like 0,1,2,---,10. Next page also I have 10 records.

I used RouterLink for View button in **product_list**. like,

```
          <td>
             <a class="badge badge-view-btn" [routerLink]="['/product/view',p.id]">View </a>
          </td>
```

And gave back button from **product_detail** to **product_list**

like

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-pill btn-lg m-b-15rem" (click)="back()">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-left fa-lg m-r-10"></i>Back</button>

  back() {
   this.location.back();
   }
```

I already applied pagination for the table also.

Challenge:

1. If I go to product 15 (page 2) and clicking on view button.
2. Then on clicking back button, I have to go page 2 itself not to 1st page. By giving `this.location.back();` it is going back to page 1.

If I have to go page 2 what I want to do??

Comment: Can you add a Demo here. In slackblitz or jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Your product list page route should include the pagination index also.
Ex:/product/product_list?pageIndex=1

So when the next & previous button click event change the router queryParam then you can listen to the route change event and update data. Now because page info included in the router when you call 'this.location.back()' this will automatically take you to correct pagination

Comment: is there any option for passing the value with this.location.back()

Comment: No. Other option might be save the current pagination index in some service and read it from whenever product list page load